# Can't connect to Gear S2 using sdb

Tags: tizen-sdb

I'm trying to connect from my OS X Mavericks machine to my Gear S2 device.

1. I have enabled debugging on the watch
2. I had made sure that the watch is on the same network as the machine that runs sdb; the ip address is 192.168.1.106

It does not matter how many times I run

```
$ ./sdb connect 192.168.1.106
```

I keep getting

```
error: failed to connect to remote target '192.168.1.106'
```

However, I can ping the watch ip address.

Moreover, if I run

```
$ ./sdb devices
```

I get

```
List of devices attached 
192.168.1.106:26101     offline     <unknown>
192.168.1.106:26101     unauthorized    <unknown>
```

At some point, as I was waking up the watch with the back button, I saw with the Confirm Debug RSA Fingerprint screen go away. I suspect that this is part of the problem. Is there any way in which that confirmation dialog can be brought back?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how helpful this is for others, but the problem was solved after I reinstalled the tizen-sdk and factory reset the watch... simply factory reset did not help.

** 2 months later**

Same situation. This time, I had a new watch and had forgotten to **Enable Debug Mode** on it. Once Debug Mode is enabled make sure to **reset the watch after**. Then all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting the same error, in my case I simply powered the watch down and restarted and then it worked.